# How to create drop down list in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone

I am developing windows phone app. I want to create drop down list for names of states in India.
How to create drop down list in windows phone ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source [click](http://www.dotnetgeekette.com/2013/05/how-to-create-simple-dropdown-in.html)

ListPicker control in the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/), which provides many additional controls and pieces of functionality for Windows Phone development.  It's not native to Visual Studio, but it's easy to install and use in apps.  For a detailed tutorial on how to install it, I recommend you read [this post](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/how-to-install-windows-phone-toolkit---october-2012--8-0-sdk--via-nuget)

The ListPicker control has two modes of display: expansion mode and full-screen mode.  By default, if there are five or fewer items in the ListPicker, the data will display in expansion mode, which most resembles a dropdown.  If there are more than five items, the data will display in its own screen.

The XAML for adding a ListPicker is quite simple.  If you want to hard-code your values in the ListPicker (and you have fewer than six items), your code will look something like this:
[image]

This works great if your options aren't likely to change.  However, if you need to programmatically add values to the ListPicker, you'll add this code to your MainPage.xaml.cs file:
[image]

Alternatively, if the ListPicker values will be populated from a datasource, you have this option:
[image]

In all of these examples, since the number of items is fewer than six, the ListPicker will expand in place:[image]